# Unable to upgrade esxi to 6.5u2 due to dependency issue

Tags: esxi, vmware-server

I am receiving the error message below when trying to upgrade from 6.5 to 6.5U2 via escli.  I have tried the upgrade process with the auto download and have tried downloading the zip file to the datastore.

[DependencyError]
 VIB VMware_locker_tools-light_10.3.2.9925305-10176879 requires esx-version >= 6        .6.0, but the requirement cannot be satisfied within the ImageProfile.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?  I can not go to 6.7 due to processor incompatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove tools-light:

   ```
   esxcli software vib remove --vibname=tools-light
   ```
2. Then you can upgrade to the latest 6.5.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue.  Removed tools-light and was able to upgrade normally through esxcli